# Apply a Substr to a distinct result in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, substr

In Oracle, I need to do the average of a column (timeInmillis) from a join query that shows "duplicated" values (relative to the timeInmillis column from table1). I need to mantain the values from the join, but get the right result for the average.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
select AVG(SUBSTR(DISTINCT(concat(id1,timeInMillis)),LENGTH(id1)+1,LENGTH(CONCAT(id1,timeInMillis)))), someColumn, otherColumn 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2  ON t1.id1 = t2.id1 group by somestuff,someotherStuff;
```

If I try to do this, I get:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

This would be an example:

Table1:

```
id1 timeInMillis otherColumn
1       5            X
2       15           X
```

Table2:

```
id2  id1 otherColumn
--------------------
1     1       X
2     1       X
3     2       X
```

From my join I get a resultset like this:

```
id1 id2 timeInmillis moreColumns
--------------------------------
1    1      5           X
1    2      5           X  
2    3      15          X
```

I need to get the average of 5 and 15 (with distinct id1), but I can't modify the where part of the sql (cause of the other values I'm getting)

```
My result should be:

AVG(TIMEINMILLIS)    otherResults
----------------------------------  
10                   'whatever'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it works for the whole selected row. Can you provide sample data and expected result, and we will perhaps understand what you are tryig to do.

Comment: it's a little bit difficult to explain it, but I've did edited the question in order to do it.

Comment: I still don't get it. "The avarage of 5 and 15 (with distinct id1)"? What has the 15 to do with ID 1? And why are there two IDs even? In your sample query you join two tables with their IDs *matching*; in your sample data you have records with *different* IDs. Could you please edit your question again and tell us what you are trying to do?

Comment: Let's say table1 has id1 and timeInMillis and table2 has id2, id1. We get a result like this from the join. So, I need to get the average of time in millis when id1 is distinct from my resultset

Comment: Okay, I think I'm getting closer :-) You only want to look at ID1. For ID1 = 1 you want to get the avarage of (5,5) which is 5. For ID 2 you want to get the avarage of 15 which is 15 of course. Or do you want to get the avarage of (5,5,15)? And then, how many rows do you want in your results? All three, each showing the additional avarage in a column? Or only 2, one for ID1=1 and one for ID1=2?

Comment: considering the case above, I want the average of (5,15), so it should be 10 (20/2) as if I had not the join with the table2. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output. that will help us alot to understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

1) Option

```
 select  SUBSTR(someColumn,n,m) from ( 
      select DISTINCT someColumn  from MYTABLE
    );
```

2) Option

```
select DISTINCT SUBSTR(someColumn,n,m) from MYTABLE;
```

*) Queries can return different result.

Comment: The first one is Ok, but I can't use it to solve my problem. The second one, is not what I'm trying to do... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. You can try somthing like this either:-

```
select avg(TimeInMillis), other_cols_as_well
from(SELECT TAB1.id1, TAB2.id2, avg(TimeInMillis) as TimeInMillis
FROM TAB1, TAB2
WHERE TAB1.id1 = TAB2.id1
group by TAB1.id1, TAB2.id2) temp
where temp.id1 <> temp.id2
group by other_cols_as_well
```

Here is the fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1fc017/16

Comment: I know it's wrong, that's why I'm asking how to do it. Your query's not what I'm trying to do, I need to do the distinct values, and after that, pick some characters of the result set.Thanks anyway...

Comment: Thanks again. Your solution actually works to the avg value, but not solves my problem. I need to mantain the "group by" of the inner select, and the values of the outer select, should show the "group by" results of the inner query, not just the average time. I guess there's no way to do what I'm trying to do without rewrite completelly the query...

Answer (score 1):

Your last edit finally explains clearly what you want. You want one line only, showing the avarage of table1's values, but of course without the duplicates that you got because of joining with table 2.

One solution is to get to the final value in two steps:

```
select avg(distinct_time), sum(sub_sum)
from
(
  select max(timeinmillis) as distinct_time, sum(some_other_colum) as sub_sum
  from (query)
  group by id1
);
```

The other solution would be to rewrite the query.

Comment: The thing is, I can't group by id1, couse I have other group by clauses defined, and I can't changue them. The other values depend on the join table. I know this sounds weird, but that's what it is. I'm starting to think that I can't do what I need this way...

Comment: Whatever you grouped by so far, this should be in the inner query. You should be able to replace `query` in `from(query)` with your complete query. So the existing GROUP BY clause is not in the way. But yes, maybe you want aggregates that you'd lose in the process described. Then rewriting the query would be your only option.